# Wordpress - add link to text in echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been editing the sticky post section of the index page and I can't seem to figure out how to make a link on the text "continue reading". Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

`echo '<a class="more-link" href="'.get_the_permalink($sticky[0]).'">'CONTINUE READING &rarr;'</a>';`

the [website](http://nativeandnest.com/blog/), if you need it.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with your single quotes, why do you have single quotes around the continue reading?

Comment: This is not the "WordPress Way".  What you are referring to is a "Read More" link, which can be (normally) automatically added to the outputted excerpt.  http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-use-the-more-tag-in-wordpress/

Comment: As Devon said, you have some extra quote marks... echo '<a class="more-link" href="'.get_the_permalink($sticky[0]).'">CONTINUE READING &rarr;</a>';

Answer (score 0):

why do You use array for that ? ... get_the_permalink($sticky[0]) ... just create link like on every other post and if You want to make some unique button for sticky just check if post is sticky

```
if ( is_sticky() ) {}
```